# Quitar un texto al final de cada parrafo - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Deseo quitar un texto al final de cada párrafo.

```
Dispongo del 1ero boton: anadir (añade un texto al final de cada parrafo) --> OK
Dispongo del 2ndo boton: quitar (quita el texto al final de cada parrafo) --> ¿?
```

¿Cómo sería la posibilidad de quitar lo que previamente he añadido? ¿Pasándole el mismo texto que he añadido?

Código **jQuery**:

```
//Añadir texto al final de cada parrafo.
$("#anadir").click(function(){
    $("p").append("<strong> Hola </strong>");
});


//Quitar texto al final de cada parrafo.
$("#quitar").click(function(){
    $("p").remove(":contains('Hola')"); /// .substr(-4); 
});
```

Me explicaré mejor: tengo X tengo con 4 parrafos, al pulsar "Añadir" añado "Hola" al final de cada parrafo, vuelvo a pulsar "Añadir" y añado "Hola" al final de cada parrafo. Si pulso seguidamente "Quitar" tendria que eliminar el último "Hola" (.substr(-4)), ¿no? pero si pulso más de 2 veces "Quitar", no puedo borrar más texto del que no sea predefinido. Si pulso más veces "Quitar" que "Añadir" hay podria estar el problema, debo controlar eso.

Comment: por en la función quitar, pones en vez de quitar?

Comment: No entiendo, otra opcion que no me funciona seria añadiendo en #quitar lo siguiente: $("p").remove(":contains('texto a buscar')");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te sugiero usar `id`´s ya que mencionas que vas a agregar texto a muchos párrafos, de ser así usa una clase.

Para quitar el ultimo agregado es cuestión de recorrer todos los párrafos y buscar el ultimo `<span>` para quitarlo del texto, ejemplo:

```
$("#quitar").on("click", function() {
  //seleccionamos todos los parrafos y los recorremos con un each()
  $(".parrafo").each(function(index, elem) {
    //elem es el párrafo seleccionado en el cual vamos a buscar el elemento a eliminar
    $(elem).find('.quitar:last').remove();
  });
});
```

**Ejemplo funcionando:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#agregar").on("click", function() {
    $(".parrafo").append("<span class='quitar'>Hola Mundo!</span>");
  });
  $("#quitar").on("click", function() {
    $(".parrafo").each(function(index, elem) {
      $(elem).find('.quitar:last').remove();
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="parrafo">Este texto no se elimina. </p>
<p class="parrafo">Este texto no se elimina. </p>
<p class="parrafo">Este texto no se elimina. </p>

<button id="agregar">Agregar texto</button>
<button id="quitar">Quitar texto</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta JuankGlezz, el problema viene que en mi HTML (no se puede modificar), los párrafos se llaman de la siguiente manera: <p class="primerparrafo"> <p class="segundoparrafo"> <p class="tercerparrafo"> todos ellos dentro de un <div> llamado "contenido", que a su vez está dentro de un <body>.

Comment: @omaza1990 el ejemplo solo es un ejemplo, solo hay que hacerle las modificaciones en tu caso html no se puede modificar, pero si puedes modificar el javascript en este caso `$('.parrafo')` pasaría a ser `$('p[class$="parrafo"]')` lo cual busca todos los `<p>` que tengan una clase que termine en párrafo más informacion en [este enlace](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/), si quieres saber mas formas de seleccionar [observa este enlace](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 3):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente a ver si esto te funciona.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    
    var cont=-1;
    
    $("#agregar").on("click",function(){
          cont++;
          $("#parrafo").append("<span id='"+cont+"'>Hola Mundo!</span>");
    });
    $("#quitar").on("click",function(){
        $("#"+cont).remove();
        cont--;
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenedor">
    <p id="parrafo"></p>
</div>

<button id="agregar">Agregar texto</button>
<button id="quitar">Quitar texto</button>
```

uso `span` y un contador para ir llevando el control de lo que agrego, y despues voy eliminando el último.

Comment: Me funciona en bucle pero unicamente en el primer parrafo, en los demás me los añade pero no los borra. En el primero si los borra.

Comment: por que ocupas el mismo contador para todos, si necesitas que haya independencia, puedes crear un objeto que vaya manejando esto individualmente.

Comment: Independencia no, deberia ser colectivo, si añado "Hola mundo" a todos, también podre eliminar el "Hola mundo" a todos, ¿no?

Comment: Tal vez no estoy entendiendo bien, me podrías decir que es a lo que te refieres , en que lo metiste a un bucle?

Answer (score 1):

Si sabes, la cantidad de caracteres que deseas quitar al final, es decir siempre van a ser 10 o 20 un ejemplo lo puedes quitar con la funcion substr
[substr ejemplos en jquery](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp)

```
/* Se aplica a tu id o nombre o en este caso a tu parrafo y el -7 es la cantidad de caracteres que quieres quitar */    

.substr(-7);
```

Comment: Podria ser una solucion, pero si pulso más veces quitar de las que di en añadir, quito el texto predefinido, y eso es lo que no quiero. Me explicaré mejor: tengo X tengo con 4 parrafos, al pulsar "Añadir" añado "Hola" al final de cada parrafo, vuelvo a pulsar "Añadir" y añado "Hola" al final de cada parrafo. Si pulso seguidamente "Quitar" tendria que eliminar el último "Hola" (.substr(-4)), ¿no? pero si pulso más de 2 veces "Quitar", no puedo borrar más texto del que no sea predefinido. Si pulso más veces "Quitar" que "Añadir" hay podria estar el problema, debo controlar eso.